# Homomorphisms and generators

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi: G_{1} \rightarrow G_{2}$ be a homomorphism and $G_{1} = \langle a \rangle$ and $G_{2} = \langle b \rangle$ be infinite cyclic groups. Must we have $\phi(a) = b$?

Comment: Why cant $\phi(a)=b^0=e$ Where e is the identity of $G_2$

Comment: Prove that if $b$ is a generator, then so is $b^{-1}$.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @ChrisEagle it shows that there are at least two isomorphisms between $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: OH I think the question should have been about isommorphisms not homomorphisms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No every $\phi:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ with $\phi(\alpha)=(\beta)^k$ is a **monomorphism**  of groups  for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ ( $k\neq 0$, if $k=0$ then it's the trivial homomorpishm)

If you have $k=1$ or $k=-1$ then $\phi$ is an **isomorphism** of groups.

If what bothers you is “how we can fit” one infinite cyclic group into another infinite cyclic group if we don't map one generator to the other. Then just remember that every **subgroup of an infinite cyclic group is also infinite cyclic**.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not. For example, let $G_1=G_2=\Bbb{Z}, a=b=1$. Then for any integer $k\neq1$, $\phi(n)=kn$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

As a counterexample, consider the zero homomorphism, that takes any generator to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant *isomorphism*. But even then, for $G_1=G_2=\Bbb{Z}/\Bbb{Z/p}, a=b=1$, $\phi(n)=kn$ with any $k$ coprime to $p$ and $k$ not congruent $1 \mod p$ is a counterexample.